# Поиск текста с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, поиск

Осуществляю поиск текста

```
self.l_vid = re.findall('(?<=деятельности, на который выдана лицензия\n)+?(?=\n\d+\n)', text)
```

Однако получаю пустой список.

Отрывок текст с искомым значение по [ссылке](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/bQVo7yi23nX3WA)

Answer (score 0):

мне вот так помогло (проверял ваш текст на https://regex101.com/):

```
(?<=деятельности, на который выдана лицензия\n)[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ ,\n]*(?=\n\d+\n)
```

В общем какие-то проблемки с текстом

ну и аккуратнее с экранированием у себя - одно дело `\n` и другое дело `\d`, используйте r-строки

Comment: Спасибо, работает.